# GoLand import go module public repo fails with invalid version

Tags: go, goland, go-modules

I want to import a module I have created into another project. The source code is in GitHub, in a public repo, but I get the following error when trying to import in GoLand:

```
go: finding module for package github.com/ambye85/gophercises/link
go: downloading github.com/ambye85/gophercises/link v0.0.0-20200323082040-d484a876f7e8
go: downloading github.com/ambye85/gophercises v0.0.0-20200323082040-d484a876f7e8
github.com/ambye85/gophercises/sitemap imports
    github.com/ambye85/gophercises/link: github.com/ambye85/gophercises/link@v0.0.0-20200323082040-d484a876f7e8: verifying module: github.com/ambye85/gophercises/link@v0.0.0-20200323082040-d484a876f7e8: reading https://sum.golang.org/lookup/github.com/ambye85/gophercises/link@v0.0.0-20200323082040-d484a876f7e8: 410 Gone
    server response:
    not found: github.com/ambye85/gophercises/link@v0.0.0-20200323082040-d484a876f7e8: invalid version: git fetch -f origin refs/heads/*:refs/heads/* refs/tags/*:refs/tags/* in /tmp/gopath/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/a488fe783593bd6e7b765f40dfed37c7e534d0a80ca8e1bff63e11e21f02e8fd: exit status 128:
        fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': terminal prompts disabled
```

All the searching I have done seems to indicate that this is caused by trying to access a private repo. That is not the case here.

Does anyone know what the cause and fix is?

Output of `go env`:

```
go env
GO111MODULE=""
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOCACHE="/Users/ashleyb/Library/Caches/go-build"
GOENV="/Users/ashleyb/Library/Application Support/go/env"
GOEXE=""
GOFLAGS=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="darwin"
GOINSECURE=""
GONOPROXY=""
GONOSUMDB=""
GOOS="darwin"
GOPATH="/Users/ashleyb/go"
GOPRIVATE=""
GOPROXY="https://proxy.golang.org,direct"
GOROOT="/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.14/libexec"
GOSUMDB="sum.golang.org"
GOTMPDIR=""
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.14/libexec/pkg/tool/darwin_amd64"
GCCGO="gccgo"
AR="ar"
CC="clang"
CXX="clang++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
GOMOD=""
CGO_CFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_CPPFLAGS=""
CGO_CXXFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_FFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_LDFLAGS="-g -O2"
PKG_CONFIG="pkg-config"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fno-caret-diagnostics -Qunused-arguments -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/var/folders/pn/8n7495nd5yn6mxxthgv5ghqhtn2mwj/T/go-build279336926=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches -fno-common"
```

Comment: Facing the same issue. was your error resolved? If yes, what did you do for it?

Comment: It was an access issue to a private repository.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Can be fixed using:

```sh
$ git config --global --add url."git@github.com:".insteadOf "https://github.com/"
```

This problem may occur when you’re trying to authenticate with `https` but you have 2FA enabled. This can be solved by forcing git to use `ssh` for all interactions.

Resources:

- [Adding a new SSH key to your GitHub account](https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account)
- [Blog post](https://jacopretorius.net/2018/05/git-error-could-not-read-username.html)

Comment: Even with public repos?